# Compare variable to cell in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables, compare

I have a vba script that I want to compare a ItemNumber that is received from a Macro Userform.  But for some reason it does not work if I use the ItemNumber variable.  The number is being passed because if I tell it to set the call to that variable it does set correctly.

I have this vba script that works if I change the

```
   If ItemNumber = myRange.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
```

statement to be

```
   If "991182" = myRange.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
```

```
Sub subtract(Qty, ItemNumber, OptionButton1, OptionButton2, OptionButton3, OptionButton4, OptionButton5, OptionButton6)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim r As Double, c As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("On Hands")
    Set myRange = ws.Range("A3:A10")
    For r = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        ' For c = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count

        If ItemNumber = myRange.Cells(r, 1).Value Then
            If OptionButton1 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value - Qty
                MsgBox "Removed " + Qty + " from your On Hands Sheet Item #: " + ItemNumber
            End If
            If OptionButton2 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value - Qty
                MsgBox "Removed " + Qty + "from your On Hands Sheet Item #: " + ItemNumber
            End If
            If OptionButton3 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value - Qty
                MsgBox "Removed " + Qty + " from your On Hands Sheet Item #: " + ItemNumber
            End If
            If OptionButton4 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value + Qty
                MsgBox "Added " + Qty + " to your On Hands Sheet Item #: " + ItemNumber
            End If
            If OptionButton5 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value + Qty
                MsgBox "Added " + Qty + " to your On Hands Sheet Item #: " + ItemNumber
            End If
            If OptionButton6 = True Then
                myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value + Qty
                MsgBox "Added " + Qty + " to your On Hands Sheet for Item #: " + ItemNumber
                '    myRange.Cells(r, 3) = myRange.Cells(r, 3).Value + Qty

            End If
        End If
        'Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the value of `ItemNumber` assigned to that variable?

Comment: @JeremyLarson Does `Debug.print ItemNumber` return something ?

Comment: Use proper indentation, please. This bites my eyes. You can automate your indention using RubberDuck VBA.

Comment: Your ItemNumber is propably a string (or Long etc. but no Variant), dimension it

Comment: So try: If Clng(ItemNumber) = ....

Comment: The ItemNumber is passed from Another sub routine but originally came from a Macro Userform1.   I have a feeling it has something to do with the the cell and variable since it works when I use "991182" instead.  Ill try the debug.print and see what that does,  I do know that the ItemNumber is passing the correct info because i had it print to another cell just fine using the same script..

Comment: So clng(ItemNumber) did work when the number is just a number.  But alot of my numbers have an R after them which makes them text.  then clng doesnt work so 991182R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you got `Char` into `ItemNumber` you can do as follow :

```
If CStr(ItemNumber) = Cstr(myRange.Cells(r, 1).Value) Then
```

It will convert `ItemNumber` into a `string` and the cells value to

Comment: @JeremyLarson Glad I could help you